# I'm trying to compare two words in a file

Tags: python-3.x, file

Trying to compare two words in a file and make a graph with words being nodes and connections being edges if the nodes only differ by a single letter.

I have the nodes down. I just need to figure out how to do the edges. I have a file: words.txt. words.txt contains these words below all on different lines:

```
fools
cools
pools
polls
poles
pales
sales
sages
```

I'm trying to write a function that basically creates an edge between words that only differ by a letter. I started here:

```
FILE = open(words.txt, "r")
for line in FILE:
    **assign word1**? e.g., word1=fools
    **assign word2**? e.g., word2=cools
```

once the words are assigned I can pass them into my other function that compares them and assigns an edge since they only differ by the first letter.

Comment: Are the words in `words.txt` already arranged such that each pair e.g. line1 and line2, line3 and line4 differ by only one letter?

Comment: yea. But that's not the principle I'm looking for.  Vineeth below pretty much summed up my issue.

Comment: @VineethSai Purely accidental..new here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way you can do it, I've just added a print statement to simulate a node. But I'm sure you can figure out how to construct a graph by yourself.

```
s = '''fools
cools
pools
polls
poles
pales
sales
sages'''

words = s.split('\n') # Do this properly according to your file structure
print(words)
for i in range(len(words)):
    word1 = words[i]
    for j in range(len(words)):
        word2 = words[j]
        res = [index for index in range(len(word1)) if word1[index] != word2[index]]
        if len(res) == 1: # They differ by one word
            print(word1,'---->', word2) # just arbitary node
```

Outputs:

```
fools ----> cools
fools ----> pools
cools ----> fools
cools ----> pools
pools ----> fools
pools ----> cools
pools ----> polls
polls ----> pools
polls ----> poles
poles ----> polls
poles ----> pales
pales ----> poles
pales ----> sales
sales ----> pales
sales ----> sages
sages ----> sales
```

And here's a pluggable function , might help you.

```
def differ_by_one_word(word1, word2):
    '''
    Returns True only if both the words differ by one letter
    '''
    res = [index for index in range(len(word1)) if word1[index] != word2[index]]
    if len(res) == 1:
        return True
    else:
        return False

print(differ_by_one_word('fools', 'pools'))
print(differ_by_one_word('fools', 'drools'))
```

Outputs:

```
True
False
```